# ScalaXML and empty lines

Tags: xml, scala, whitespace, implicit-conversion, removing-whitespace

I'm just getting started in `scala` and have an issue with representing my domain object (`case class`) to a well-formatted XML. I have the following implicit converter:

```
implicit def identifierToXml(ident : Identifier): Elem =
    <identifier>
        { if(ident.use != null) <use value={ident.use}/> }
        { if(ident.label != null) <label value={ident.label}/> }
        { if(ident.system != null) <system value={ident.system}/> }
        { if(ident.value != null) <value value={ident.value}/> }
        { if(ident.period != null) <period>{ident.period}</period> }
        { if(ident.assigner != null) <assigner>{ident.assigner}</assigner> }
    </identifier>
```

It works great, except for the fact that it injects empty lines on missing values. For instance `Identifier(system = "test")` results in:

```
<identifier>


    <system value="test"/>



</identifier>
```

I know that I can use `scala.xml.Utility.trim(...)` to covert into a completely trimmed representation (`<identifier><system value="test"/></identifier>`) but would rather keep the formatting with the exception of empty lines.

How can I achieve this in an idiomatic way? If I was to use `scala.xml.Utility.trim(...)`, is there a nice way to add this to my implicit converter?

NB. Also, if there is any better way to deal with such conversion between `object <-> xml` representation, I'd love to hear suggestions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is just that when constructing the XML literal, every new line is translated to an XML new line.  If all you care about is viewing this and turning it into a string, you could use `scala.xml.PrettyPrinter`:

```
val printer = new PrettyPrinter(100, 2)
printer.format(myDiv)
```

If you want to get an element from that string, you could use `loadString`:

```
XML.loadString(printer.format(myDiv))
```

But you could probably just use `scala.xml.Utility.trim`, like you said, and then print it using `PrettyPrint`.  You could even override `toString` for the object if that fits your structure.